# jspath with angular js

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Been developing a angular js app, lets say i have a directive, which has a object set from controller.

i.e

```
 scope{
     prop: '=',
     object: '=',
    }
```

Directive renders template like this

`<input ng-name="prop.name" type="number" ng-model="object[prop.xpath]"/>` where property path is path to object model. For example

```
  Person {
   String firstName;
   String lastName;
   }
```

then prop.xpath value can be firstName where object is person instance.

how to specifiy this in the ng-model?

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: unclear what you're asking

Comment: how do i specify, jsonpath  in the ng-model?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is too localized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the above code does work, my property location was wrong.. so i answered my question i think